# Are there any known issues in running an Intel i7-7700 processor and Intel HD Graphics 630?

Tags: intel-graphics, intel, cpu

I am planning a new PC build and would like to know if the most current generation of intel processors is supported, specifically the integrated graphics as I don't have a need for a dedicated GPU. So far all I can tell is that 16.04 will not work, 16.10 might (?).

What issues could be expected?

I understand that the latest kernel maybe necessary, is it worth waiting for the next Ubuntu release? The availability of the previous generation of intel's processors is dwindling so I'm a bit stuck as to what to do.

Any help greatly appreciated, I have had no luck in the UbuntuWiki so far. Is there a specific topic I could run in my searches here or elsewhere? Has anyone had success with this setup?

Comment: IIRC, I read about Ubuntu 16.04 working on a recent laptop. What problems did you encounter when installing 16.04?

Comment: No problems yet, I haven't got my new processor. I just want to be ready for what I might be getting into  with the latest integrated graphics from intel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just general advice I'd give is to wait for the next release, as older kernels will most certainly not function. The 17.04 builds are running well (for unstable) on a couple Kaby Lake systems of mine, as well as Ryzen. I personally don't think using 16.10 would be the best move, as it is still a little older, but also because 17.04 is less than a month away, and will have more support as well as knowledge base on this topic in particular.

Comment: Thanks Schyken, that's sound advice. It's only a few weeks so no harm in waiting.  You'll probably get the answer tick, but lets wait, that was a really fast response.

Comment: 16.04 would not work from a live usb:  definitely display issues (flickering and monitor going to sleep), effectively didn't work. Although it may have worked with no display output.   16.10 worked well as did 17.04, neither with issues. Now just have to wait for the final release of 17.04.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to Schyken, I'd rather go with the current Ubuntu LTS, which is 16.04 at the moment. I would be really surprised, if such a standard setup, Intel processor with internal graphics, would give any issues. Especially, when you remember Intel always contributing drivers to the Linux kernel.

Searching for [ubuntu i7 7700](https://www.google.de/search?q=ubuntu+i7+7700) leads to [Ubuntu Certification i7-7700](https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/component/dmi/4103/dmi%3AIntel(R)Core(TM)i7-7700CPU@3.60GHz/) and [Ubuntu on Dell Vostro 3668](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201610-25170/), which hints at some support at least.

There are also some pages talking about benchmarking i7-7700K with Linux, so it shouldn't be too hard to get this system running. At most, I would expect to build your own vanilla kernel, but most likely you will be able to go with the one supplied by Ubuntu.

---

*Update:*

Recently, I bought a laptop with an i5-7200U processor. As expected, the 16.04 worked out of the box.

What didn't work out of the box was suspend and resume, because of the 4.4 kernel, which is installed by default. Although, upgrading to linux-image-4.10, which is provided by 16.04, fixed this problem.